# Search and replace characters in XML file using regular expression

Tags: xml, expression

Help needed :) 
How to search and remove spaces in XML file (Example 2:), 
where first part (`src="fileadmin/Images/INT`) and end of the file remain the same (.png")
Result should be as (`Example 1:`)

```
Example 1: src="fileadmin/Images/INT/Icons/Icon_10x10-Download/ico_l_full.png"
Example 2: src="fileadmin/Images/INT/Ic ons/Icon_10x10-Down load/ic o_l_full.png"
```

Comment: Add more detail to your question and show us what you tried so far.

Comment: I can find and erase spaces by using \s, but i will ruin whole xml if all the spaces will be removed, i need to remove only in specific area in shown above example. Path like INT/Icons/ changes, could be INT/Uploads.. etc.